# How to add another inside an inner array property in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

So I have a state that I need to update or add an object within, below is my initial state

```
const initialState =  {
    data: [
        {
            perspective: 'test 1',
            items: [
                {
                    item1: 'item'
                },
                {
                    item1: 'item'
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            perspective: 'test 2',
            items: [
                {
                    item1: 'item'
                },
                {
                    item1: 'item'
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            perspective: 'test 2',
            items: [
                {
                    item1: 'item'
                },
                {
                    item1: 'item'
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would want to add another object inside the **items** property in any index, let say on 0 or 1, below is the object I want to insert, so with that, my target will be **data[0].items** for example

```
{
    item1: 'item'
}
```

I now have a code in redux like this, please keep in mind that [0] can be changed to any index, I just put 0 for example.

```
const insertObj = {
    item1: 'item'
}

return {
    ...state,
    data: [
      {
        ...state.data[0],
        items: [...state.data[0].items, insertObj]
      }
    ]
};
```

it's actually working and the object is being inserted but since I'm targeting index 0, the other index is being removed or deleted, w/c it shouldn't be, so if I run the state the output will be like this

```
const initialState =  {
    data: [
        {
            perspective: 'test 1',
            items: [
                {
                    item1: 'item'
                },
                {
                    item1: 'item'
                },
                {
                    item1: 'item'
                },
            ]
        },
}
```

I think there's something wrong the state that I'm doing, any help will be appreciated, please also keep note that I can select any index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
const insertObj = {
    item1: 'item'
}

const newData = [...state.data];
newData[0].items.push(insertObj);

return {
    data: newData
};
```

Comment: this works @Surya but how would you interpret it in a redux way? I mean without using any push or const, by just using spread. Thanks for the answer btw!